# Генераторы чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо написать генератор генерирующий последовательность степеней числа по модулю до тех пор, пока очередная степень не будет равна 1.

Я не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы когда результат равен единице прекратить вычисления. Просто, заранее не знаю через сколько итераций будет единица.

Код:

```
def gen_mod(x,y):
    for iii in range(0,10):
        ttt=(x**iii)%y
        yield ttt

for num in gen_mod(3,7):
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Я ведь зарание не знаю через сколько итераций будет единица.

Так на это есть условный оператор `if`. Или цикл с условием `while`

Кроме того, разумно не возводить в степень каждый раз, а просто умножать, чтобы получить следующую степень

```
def gen_mod(x, y):
    xx = 1
    ttt = 0
    while ttt != 1:
        xx *= x
        ttt=(xx)%y
        yield ttt

for num in gen_mod(3,7):
    print(num)
3
2
6
4
5
1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Валерий, [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Счетчик где?

```
def gen_mod(x,y):
count = 0
yield (x**count)%y
result = 0
while result !=1:
    count+=1
    result = (x**count)%y
    yield result
```

for num in gen_mod(3,7):
    print(num)

Comment: а зачем он там?)